# Arithmetic Calculation in Perl Substitute Pattern Matching

Tags: regex, perl

Using just **one** Perl substitute regular expression statement (`s///`), how can we write below:

Every success match contains just a string of Alphabetic characters `A..Z`. We need to substitute the match string with a substitution that will be the sum of character index (in alphabetical order) of every character in the match string.

Note: For A, character index would be 1, for B, 2 ... and for Z would be 26.

Please see example below:

```
success match: ABCDMNA  
substitution result: 38
```

Note:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 13 + 14 + 1 = 38;
```

since

```
A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4, M = 13, N = 14 and A = 1.
```

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: "comment: ..." it actually adds up to 38 of course.

Comment: No. Actually this would help me to start to understand how to do arithmetic calculation in regex in Perl.

Comment: Have you considered [this perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Embedded-Code-Execution-Frequency)?

Comment: Thanks for that source. I just skimmed through it. Actully I searched online to find a feasible way of doing this with no success. unfortnately In the perldoc you mentioned I see embeded code section but I don't know how to refer to every character in the match string in order to be able to do a calculation on it.

Comment: @mikenomax It seems as though you are using another low rep user to edit your question. You should not do this, as it will require approval from other users to do. If this is a way to circumvent your character being blocked from asking questions, I would suggest that you instead start following the guidelines for asking questions, so that your users do not get blocked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will post this as an answer, I guess, though the credit for coming up with the idea should go to [abiessu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2592931/abiessu) for the idea presented in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25676096/725418).

```
perl -ple'1 while s/(\d*)([A-Z])/$1+ord($2)-64/e'
```

Since this is clearly homework and/or of academic interest, I will post the explanation in spoiler tags.

> - We match an optional number `(\d*)`, followed by a letter `([A-Z])`. The number is the running sum, and the letter is what we need to add to the sum.
>  - By using the `/e` modifier, we can do the math, which is add the captured number to the `ord()` value of the captured letter, minus 64. The sum is returned and inserted instead of the number and the letter.
>  - We use a `while` loop to rinse and repeat until all letters have been replaced, and all that is left is a number. We use a while loop instead of the `/g` modifier to reset the match to the start of the string.

Answer (score 3):

Just [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html), translate, and [`sum`](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#%24num_or_undef-%3d-sum-%40list):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw(sum);

my $string = 'ABCDMNA';

my $sum = sum map {ord($_) - ord('A') + 1} split //, $string;

print $sum, "\n";
```

Outputs:

```
38
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you use the `/e` modifier in the substitution?

```
$s = "ABCDMNA";
$s =~ s/(.)/$S += ord($1) - ord "@"; 1 + pos $s == length $s ? $S : ""/ge;
print "$s\n"
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following matching scenario:

```
my $text = "ABCDMNA";
my $val = $text ~= s!(\d)*([A-Z])!($1+ord($2)-ord('A')+1)!gr;
```

(Without having tested it...)  This should repeatedly go through the string, replacing one character at a time with its ordinal value added to the current sum which has been placed at the beginning.  Once there are no more characters the copy (`/r`) is placed in `$val` which should contain the translated value.

Comment: This is a nice effort, though this does not work. You need a way to reset the position of the match. I did `perl -ple'1 while s/(\d*)([A-Z])/$1+ord($2)-64/e'` which will reset the regex match to the start for each new match, until all letters are consumed.

Comment: Hmm... I figured the `/g` would keep repeating like that, oh well

Comment: I'll keep this answer here to supplement yours @TLP.

Comment: +1 for the idea. Yeah, `/g` would work, if one could set the active position to before the number. I tried using `pos`, but it did not seem to work, so this was the simpler option.

Answer (score 1):

Or an short alternative:

```
echo ABCDMNA | perl -nlE 'm/(.)(?{$s+=-64+ord$1})(?!)/;say$s'
```

or readable

```
$s = "ABCDMNA";
$s =~ m/(.)(?{ $sum += ord($1) - ord('A')+1 })(?!)/;
print "$sum\n";
```

prints

```
38
```

Explanation:

- trying to match `any character` what must not followed by "empty regex". `/.(?!)/`
- Because, an empty regex matches everything, the "not follow by anything", isn't true ever.
- therefore the regex engine move to the next character, and tries the match again
- this is repeated until is exhausted the whole string.
- because we want capture the character, using capture group `/(.)(?!)/`
- the `(?{...})` runs the perl code, what sums the value of the captured character stored in `$1`
- when the regex is exhausted (and fails), the last `say $s` prints the value of sum

from the perlre

> **(?{ code })**
>
> This zero-width assertion executes any embedded Perl code. It always
>   succeeds, and its return value is set as $^R .
>
> WARNING: Using this feature safely requires that you understand its
>   limitations. Code executed that has side effects may not perform
>   identically from version to version due to the effect of future
>   optimisations in the regex engine. For more information on this, see
>   Embedded Code Execution Frequency.